# word 2016: print list of built-in word commands and assigned shortcuts

Tags: list, ms-word, command

Re: Word 2016. Is there a way to print a list of of built-in Word commands along with assigned shortcut keys, if any?  The list can be seen by clicking on "Customize Ribbon/Customize Keyboard/All Commands", but how can the full list be printed?

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums.

Comment: See my first comment. This is off-topic. Look at my article on getting such a list here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/create-a-list-of-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft/7952be51-6a8e-4382-994c-e6632ba4cf35?tm=1589698042191 If you have questions after that, post a question in the appropriate forum.